# cropping a viewController to fit iphone screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

So I have a viewController `viewController.m` which is 320*568 but I would like this to change to 320*480 if the iphone is an iphone 4. I have the correct code to show if it is an iphone 4 like so:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    //crop view controller dimensions to 320*480
}
```

But I would like to do this without squishing any `UIImageView` or `UITable` inside the `viewController` like it does when you edit the simulated size height to "Freeform".

Answer (score 1):

The way you doing above will waste your time. The best option for you in this case is the [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You should define your own constraints so that subviews including `UIImageView` and `UITableView` fit always on their super view which is the view controller.

Here is a good article to get you started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: But isn't autolayout designed with rotating in mind not different screen sizes

Comment: It's for both, Auto Layout is mainly to allow your app responds appropriately to changes in screen size, device orientation and hence to make your subviews fit to different sizes and orientations. Take some time to master this technology because you will need it a lot.